# how do i get the indexpath of the button in the tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a button in my `tableViewCell` , that has a segue to another `view controller`. I'm trying to pass a `PostArray[indexpath.row].postKey` from the `tableViewCell` to the `viewcontroller` via prepare for segue method. I tried different approaches like getting the `indexpath` on touch position , but don't think that would be a definitive solution. Any suggestions, i can achieve this?

also, i have tagged my buttons in the `cellForRowAt` func

```
cellData.openBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cellData.openBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: `@objc func openPressed(_ sender : UIButton) { 
 let index = sender.tag
}` does this solve your issue ? You can easily get the index by sender.tag

Comment: A `UIButton` with `addTarget`?  Is that a new norm of 2020?

Comment: @ElTomato It's quite old. `UIButton` inherits from `UIControl`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift target/action is pretty old-fashioned and *objective-c-ish*, there is a better way.

In the custom cell add a `callback` property and an `IBAction`. Connect the `IBAction` to the button.

```
var callback : (() -> Void)?

@IBAction func openPressed(_ sender : UIButton) {
    callback?()
}
```

In `cellForRow` assign a closure to the `callback` property. In the closure call `performSegue` and pass the `postKey` as `sender`

```
let post = PostArray[indexpath.row]
cellData.callback = { 
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextIdentifier", sender: post.postKey)
}
```

In `prepare(for segue` get the key from the `sender` parameter and pass it to the destination controller

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) 
{
    guard segue.identifier == "NextIdentifier" else { return }
    let postKey = sender as! String // or whatever the static type is
    let nextViewController = segue.destination as! NextViewController
    nextViewController.postKey = postKey
}
```

---

The simple form works only if the order of the table view row will never change.

If cells can be inserted, deleted or moved you have to gather the actual index path when the closure is executed

```
var callback : ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

@IBAction func openPressed_ sender : UIButton) {
    callback?(self)
}
```

...

```
let post = PostArray[indexpath.row]
cellData.callback = { actualCell in
    let actualIndexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: actualCell)!
    let actualPost = self.PostArray[actualIndexPath.row]
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "NextIdentifier", sender: actualPost.postKey)
}
```

Replace `NextIdentifier` and `NextViewController` with the real values and delete the code lines and the action function in the question.

Comment: this is definitely much efficient than tags :)

Answer (score 1):

Button pressed get index from tableview

```
@objc func openPressed(_ sender:UIButton){
     let index = sender.tag
      print(index)
}
```

Comment: That works well in the 'openPressedBtn', I need to pass PostArray[indexPath.row].postKey to the other view controller. how do i get the indexpath.row in the prepareforsegue function

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a segue from your cell to controller, create controller to controller(so that you can call performSegue manually.).

Then do this,

```
@objc func openPressed(_ sender:UIButton){
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourIdentifer", sender: sender)
}
```

And in your prepareForSegue, do this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "YourIdentifer" {
        guard let destinationVC = segue.destination as? YourNextVC else { return }
        destinationVC.userSelectedIndex = (sender as! UIButton).tag 
    }
}
```

Comment: An extra property is not needed. You can hand over the value simply in the `sender` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

you can give a tag to cell button

```
cell.yourButton.tag = indexPath.row
```

and create IBAction in cell and get index path like

```
@objc func openPressed(_ sender:UIButton){
     let tag = sender.superview.tag
    //preform your segue code and pass array object to another view controller "PostArray[tag]"

}
```